# Angular universal pass data from node.js to client-side app

Tags: angular-universal

How to transfer data from node.js (application on the server side) to the application on the client side in angular 16 universal?

I outlined the achievement, where I pass a value from node.js to my client side app via angular DI and TransferState as you can see below.  Is this approach the recommended pattern how to resolve this problem?

project/path/src/tokens.js

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { makeStateKey } from '@angular/platform-browser';
export const TEST = new InjectionToken<string>('test');
export const VALUE = makeStateKey<string>('value');
```

project/path/server.ts

```
...
import { TEST } from '.src/tokens';
...
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    providers: [{ provide: TEST, useValue: "hello world" }],   
  }));
...
```

project/path/src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, Optional, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { TransferState } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component, inject, Inject, Optional PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { TEST, VALUE } from '../tokens';
...
export class AppComponent {
  theValue = "";
  platform = inject( TransferState );

  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(TEST) private token: string,
              @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object ){
    if (isPlatformServer(platformId)) {
      this.platform.set(VALUE, token);
    }else{
      this.theValue = this.platform.get(VALUE);
    }
  }
}
```

project/path/src/app/app.component.html

```
<span>{{theValue | json}}</span>
```